# How to return the three letter month abbreviation of a date in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I've searched here and other site without being able to find a solution.

I've been able to do this in the past but can't figure it out now. I have an effective date in, lets just say cell B1. I want to return the three letter month of that date in A1. No matter what I use I get a NUM error or a Jan as the answer no matter what the date is.

`=TEXT(DATE(2000,B1,1),"mmm")` gives me `#NUM!`

`=TEXT(DATE(year(B1),B1,1),"mmm")` gives me `#VALUE!`

`=TEXT(B1,”MMMM”)` gives me `#NAME`?

And from a post on this site nothing works either: [Excel number format to convert number of month to name of month](https://superuser.com/questions/861947/excel-number-format-to-convert-number-of-month-to-name-of-month)

P.S. I also don't get "STTR's" answer which uses colons instead of commas. I don't have enough points to reply to ask.

Comment: What is the value in B1?

Comment: I would expect that what you would want is `=text(b1,"mmm")`  Do you have backwards quotes in your third example?

Comment: FYI related to the colons vs commas; in some regions of the world they use colons instead of commas. It means the same thing.

Comment: Instead of =TEXT(DATE(year(B1),B1,1),"mmm"),  Try =TEXT(DATE(year(B1),month(B1),1),"mmm")

Comment: If B1 is actually a date, then `DATE(year(B1),month(B1),1)` is unnecessary - it just makes a new date on the first of the same month.  Since we are trying to extract the name of the month, this doesn't get us anywhere.  If B1 _is not_ a date, then `year(B1)` and `month(B1)` won't give meaningful results.

Comment: @Adam, I agree I just copied what OP mentioned and tried to work on it. After I posted my comment, I tried what you have mentioned and up voted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following formula to return the three letter month abbreviation:

```
=TEXT(B1,"mmm")
```

Where `B1` is the cell that contains the Date value.

Answer (score 5):

If **B1** appears to be a Date, but the formulas fail, then **B1** may actually have a *Text* value.  In that case use:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(B1),"mmm")
```

[image]